# Does Android check other accounts registered on device to determine if IAP is already purchased?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-account

I'm developing a game at the moment and am implementing In-App purchases (IAP). In my testing I am able to make purchases and then when I try to purchase it again Google tells me I already own product - which is good, of course.

Then I cleared cache, data and uninstalled the game, I go back to the Play Store and switched to my other account and installed the game again on the second account (IAP not yet purchased on this account) but when I go and purchase it it still tells me that I already own the product.

I also tested it on another device which only has my second account - and the product is indeed not purchased on that device

Does this mean Android checks my other account to see if any of the other registered account already owns a certain product? What else might be going on here?

Comment: Devices have a primary account.  I wouldn't be surprised if that's all it checked, not the secondaries at all.  But I have never tested this.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yeah the primary account is actually the Second account (which doesn't have the IAP purchased)